# How do I run HTTP requests from a pool of threads using Celluloid?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, actor, celluloid

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, and testing it on Mac OSX 10.7.

I have a `Sender` class which is supposed to send requests to some URL:

```
require "celluloid"
require "curb"

class Sender
  include Celluloid

  def send(msg)    
    Curl.get($URL) do |url|
      url.headers["content-type"] = "text/html;charset=utf-8"
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    $LOG.error "[erro]-> [ #{e.message} "
  end
end
```

I have another process which is supposed to receive messages from a RabbitMQ queue and send requests using `Sender`:

```
 AMQP.start(:host => $AMQP_URL) do |connection|
   @channel ||= AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
   @queue   ||= @channel.queue("results")

   pool = Sender.pool

   @queue.subscribe do |metadata, body|
      msg = MessagePack.unpack(body)        
      pool.send(msg)
  end
 end
```

When I run it I'm getting:

```
15:56:59 results.1    | I, [2013-02-12T15:56:59.422192 #44490]  INFO -- : Terminating 5 actors...
15:56:59 results.1    | E, [2013-02-12T15:56:59.422640 #44490] ERROR -- : Celluloid::PoolManager crashed!
15:56:59 results.1    | NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/macosx.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:81:in `load'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:81:in `load_file'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in load_all'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:38:in `each'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:38:in `block in load_all'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:35:in `each'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:35:in `load_all'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/collection.rb:72:in `fact'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in singletonclass'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid.rb:37:in `cores'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/pool_manager.rb:12:in `initialize'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:57:in `dispatch'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:323:in `block in handle_message'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:22:in `block in initialize'
15:56:59 results.1    | E, [2013-02-12T15:56:59.423117 #44490] ERROR -- : Celluloid::PoolManager#finalize crashed!
15:56:59 results.1    | NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/pool_manager.rb:26:in `finalize'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:376:in `block in run_finalizer'
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:22:in `block in initialize'
15:56:59 results.1    | I, [2013-02-12T15:56:59.424508 #44490]  INFO -- : Shutdown completed cleanly
15:56:59 results.1    | /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/macosx.rb:39:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
15:56:59 results.1    |   from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:81:in `load'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:81:in `load_file'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in load_all'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:38:in `each'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:38:in `block in load_all'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:35:in `each'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:35:in `load_all'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter/util/collection.rb:72:in `fact'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/facter-1.6.13/lib/facter.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in singletonclass'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid.rb:37:in `cores'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/pool_manager.rb:12:in `initialize'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:57:in `dispatch'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:323:in `block in handle_message'
15:56:59 results.1    |     from /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:22:in `block in initialize'
15:56:59 results.1    | exited with code 1
```

Am I doing anything wrong to make the processes crash because of the pool manager?

Comment: You are getting what? Please don't link to another site and make us chase down the error message, or image in your question. *WHEN* the link breaks, which it will eventually, your question won't make sense to people looking for an answer to the same question.

Comment: Ok I added the error message here, hope this can help ..

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is negatively demonstrated in [Reel](http://github.com/celluloid/reel). Specifically in its Rack handler. You can dive in right here and reverse engineer everything you need from there:

- https://github.com/celluloid/reel/blob/master/lib/rack/handler/reel.rb#L41

Reel is an awesome demonstration of Celluloid(::IO)'s capabilities, and exactly what you want... except in reverse. It receives requests through a pool, the negative of your case.

The main thing here as you know, is you are talking to PoolManager, not any one Actor. This is the main piece you can rethink your approach. Refactor with this in mind:

```
Celluloid::Actor[:reel_rack_pool] = ::Reel::RackWorker.pool(size: options[:workers], args: [self])
    ::Reel::Server.supervise_as(:reel_server, options[:host], options[:port]) do |connection|
    Celluloid::Actor[:reel_rack_pool].handle(connection.detach)
end
```

Feel free to update your question with new errors or issues once you take that code into account. You would definitely get help on #celluloid on freenode (IRC) and/or in the mailinglist for Celluloid which is very active and full of dedicated and knowledgeable people who are really welcoming of people unaccustomed to the ins-and-outs of Celluloid.

- http://groups.google.com/group/celluloid-ruby

Comment: I think I used wrong method name "send" in my case, when I changed the name of the method things went ok, thanks for ur willing to help here

Comment: You've clearly thought about this, but this answer is strange. Would you mind actually responding to the question with the details of how to do it?

Comment: @aronchick if the problem still exists for the OP, sure I can do that. But this uses celluloid-0.13.2 and we're now releasing 0.17.0, reel-rack was extracted, and PoolManager was extracted into its own gem ( although still included in standard Celluloid for the time being ). I highly doubt this issue still exists. But you're right, my answer is strange, and it's a good question. I'd still be willing to try to reproduce and resolve the issue if it still exists.

Comment: Actually, I stumbled on this while looking for a post about Http pooling & Celluloid generally, and that's what I was hoping to find from your answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm part of Celluloid now so I saw your question on GitHub. Sounds like you want to use http.rb ... contact me/us if you have a problem ( ideally IRC or the Google group.